# Adding dictionary keys and values after line split?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have for instance the file:

```
;;;
;;;
;;;
A  1 2 3
B  2 3 4
C  3 4 5
```

And I want to read it into a dictionary of {str: list of str} :

```
{'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['2', '3', '4'], 'C': ['3', '4', '5']
```

I have the following code:

```
d = {}
with open('file_name') as f:
    for line in f:
        while ';;;' not in line:
            (key, val) = line.split('  ')
        #missingcodehere    
return d
```

What should I put in after the line.split to assign the keys and values as a str and list of str?

Answer (score 4):

To focus on your code and what you are doing wrong.

You are pretty much in an infinite loop with your `while ';;;' not in line`. So, you want to change your logic with how you are trying to insert data in to your dictionary. Simply use a conditional statement to check `if ';;;'` is in your line.

Then, when you get your key and value from your `line.strip().split('   ')` you simply just assign it to your dictionary as `d[key] = val`. However, you want a list, and val is currently a string at this point, so call split on val as well.

Furthermore, you do not *need* to have parentheses around `key and val`. It provides unneeded *noise* to your code.

The end result will give you:

```
d = {}
with open('new_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ';;;' not in line:
            key, val = line.strip().split('  ')
            d[key] = val.split()

print(d)
```

Using your sample input, output is:

```
{'C': ['3', '4', '5'], 'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['2', '3', '4']}
```

Finally, to provide an improvement to the implementation as it can be made *more Pythonic*. We can simplify this code and provide a small improvement to split more generically, rather than counting explicit spaces:

```
with open('new_file.txt') as fin:
    valid = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fin if ';;;' not in line)
    d = {k:v.split() for k, v in valid}
```

So, above, you will notice our split looks like this: `split(None, 1)`. Where we are providing a `maxsplit=1`.

Per the docstring of `split`, it explains it pretty well:

> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>   splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
>   whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
>   removed from the result.

Finally, we simply use a dictionary comprehension to obtain our final result.

Comment: @Vlad You are very welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped solve your problem as it indicates to others what was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
def make_dict(f_name):
    with open(f_name) as f:
        d = {k: v.split() 
             for k, v in [line.strip().split('  ') 
                          for line in f 
                          if ';;;' not in line]}

    return d
```

Then

```
>>> print(make_dict('file_name'))
{'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['2', '3', '4'], 'C': ['3', '4', '5']}
```

Comment: This code is very bad. It is not flexible. Why use a generator, if you will  not write this code in one line?

Comment: @JRazor: FWIW, it's a dictionary comprehension, not a generator.